# How long does it take to insert / remove string mute?

Tags: strings, mute, violin-family

I'm writing a piece where is necessary to switch the use of the mute on the string session.
To become possible, I need to know how much time in seconds do I need to give the musicians to change the insertion and removal of the mute?

Comment: Is this for violin?

Comment: Violins, Violas, Cellos and Basses